# Replace whitespace whitespace and put string a new array

Tags: javascript

I would like to remove all whitespace and special char and put ever nummer in a new array like this: `var numbers = ['17','9','18','4A'];`

This what i am doing to remove whitespace and special character, but how do put clean it more and put in a array?

```
var str = "(17 - 9), (18 - 4A)"
str.replace(/[()-\s]/g, '');
```

output: `"179,184A"`

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What is your input and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of it as removing the extra stuff and just think of it as grabbing what you want.

```js
var input = "(17 - 9), (18 - 4A)";
// Match anything which has one or more numbers or letters in a row
var pattern = /[\da-z]+/gi;
var output = input.match(pattern);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: nice, didnt know there was a match metod that you can use to search a string for at match against a regular expression.

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake Glad I could show it to you. It comes in handy a lot. Especially for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split method, it returns an array:

```
var myArray = str.replace(/[()-\s]/g, '').split(',');
```